# I'm trying to compress some files from one directory to another but I'm getting access denied on one of the directories why?

Tags: c#, winforms

In the constructor of Form1 I did:

```
contentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + "\\SF_" + currentDate;
            zippedFileDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + "\\Default_ZippedFile_Directory";
            if (!Directory.Exists(zippedFileDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(zippedFileDirectory);
            }
            if (!Directory.Exists(contentDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(contentDirectory);
            }
```

Checked with breakpoint first time `zippedFileDirectory` not exist create it and if exist nothing. Same for the `contentDirectory`.

Now I have the `contentDirectory` here:

```
C:\\Users\\bout0_000\\AppData\\Local\\Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen\\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\\SF_04-08-13
```

Inside the `contentDirectory` I have something like 10 files.

Then `zippedFileDirectory` is:

```
C:\\Users\\bout0_000\\AppData\\Local\\Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen\\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\\Default_ZippedFile_Directory
```

This directory is empty.

Then I have this `Compress()` method:

```
private void Compress()
{
            string source = contentDirectory;
            string output = zippedFileDirectory;
            string programFilesX86 = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86) + "\\Diagnostic Tool\\7z.dll";
            if (File.Exists(programFilesX86))
            {
                SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(programFilesX86);
            }
            string programFiles = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + "\\Diagnostic Tool\\7z.dll";
            if (File.Exists(programFiles))
            {
                SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(programFiles);
            }
            SevenZipCompressor compressor = new SevenZipCompressor();
            compressor.ArchiveFormat = OutArchiveFormat.Zip;
            compressor.CompressionMode = CompressionMode.Create;
            compressor.TempFolderPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
            compressor.CompressDirectory(source, output);
            Process.Start(Path.GetFullPath(zippedFileDirectory));
}
```

For some reason on the line:

```
compressor.CompressDirectory(source, output);
```

I'm getting the exception:

> Access to the path 'C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\Default_ZippedFile_Directory' is denied.
>
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2147024891
>   Message=Access to the path 'C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\Default_ZippedFile_Directory' is denied.

I don't get it why this `zippedFileDirectory` is locked or access denied ?

If I select any other directory as source for example `d:\test` there is no problem.

Comment: Do you have the file open somewhere?

Comment: This is working for me :
In the constructor i added to this line in the end \\

    zippedFileDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + "\\Default_ZippedFile_Directory\\";

And inside the compress() method i did:

    compressor.CompressDirectory(source, output + "Diagnosis_Files.zip");

Added a file name in the end.
Now its working.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of doing string addition to construct your paths, you might want to consider using Path.Combine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because you pass a directory name for the second parameter to CompressDirectory.
You should pass a file name like....

```
    string output = Path.Combine(zippedFileDirectory, "MyZipFile.7z");
    .....

    compressor.CompressDirectory(source, output);
```